# What is the difference between these 2 way of invoking Msbuild and which is faster?

Tags: msbuild

I am having a target where i am calling 2 more targets.

> Option 1

```
<Target Name="CoreBuildSubSystem" DependsOnTargets="BuildDotNETSolutions;CopySubSystemDOs;">

 </Target>
```

> Option 2

```
<Target Name="CoreBuildSubSystem">
 <MSBuild Targets="BuildDotNETSolutions" BuildInParallel="false"></MSBuild>
    <MSBuild Targets="CopySubSystemDOs" BuildInParallel="true"></MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Are they doing the same activity ? I guess the second method is faster as it is allowing BuildInParallel=True. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

These two implementations are effectively the same performance wise as **BuildDotNETSolutions** and **CopySubSystemDOs** are executed sequentially.

Stick with Option 1 as it follows better MS Build practices as you state the dependencies of the target in the DependsOnTargets attribute which lets the build engine decide if the targets are out of date if they declare inputs and outputs.
Options 1 is also more maintainable as properties and item groups are naturally accessible and you won’t need to pass them as properties on the MS Build element.

Option 2 currently doesn't allow **BuildDotNETSolutions** and **CopySubSystemDOs** to build in parallel. You need to change it as follows to allow the targets to be built in parallel. 
However this approach would build the project in a recursive fashion which will make whoever follows you curse your name.

```
<Target Name="CoreBuildSubSystem">
 <MSBuild Projects=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)
          Targets="BuildDotNETSolutions;CopySubSystemDOs" 
          BuildInParallel="true" />
</Target>
```